# Second executing CustomBuild item always logs "All outputs are up-to-date"

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I've been trying to add a second CustomBuild step to a content project using MSBuild targets. This first on (which compiles GLSL to SPIR-V) works fine with the CustomBuild item. The second one I tried however, always logs "All outputs are up-to-date". I'm quite new to MSBuild so I'm sure I'm doing something stupid. Any general input on my script is also welcome :)

I've tried converting the second CustomBuild item to a Exec item with practically the same command which worked fine. As far as I know this will not give me access to the tracker functionality. I've also tried using a different TrackerLogDirectory but that seemed to have no effect. 
I've also checked the input files and they are being passed correctly.

This is the first (working) targets file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)spv.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="SPIRVShader">
      <Targets>CompileGlslShaders</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompileGlslShaders" Condition="'@(SPIRVShader)' != ''" BeforeTargets="FinalizeBuildStatus">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Shaders;$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).tlog"/>

    <ItemGroup>
      <SPIRVShader>
        <Outputs>$(OutDir)Shaders\%(Filename)%(Extension).spv</Outputs>
        <Command>glslangValidator -V -o "$(OutDir)Shaders\%(Filename)%(Extension).spv" "%(FullPath)"</Command>
      </SPIRVShader>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CustomBuild 
      Sources="@(SPIRVShader)" 
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="True"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).tlog\"
      ErrorListRegex="(?'CATEGORY'ERROR|WARNING): (?'FILENAME'.+):(?'LINE'\d+): (?'TEXT'.*)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

And this is the second one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)pum.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="PuModel">
      <Targets>CompilePlutoniumModels</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompilePlutoniumModels" Condition="'@(PuModel)' != ''" BeforeTargets="FinalizeBuildStatus">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Models;$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).tlog"/>

    <ItemGroup>
      <CompileModels>
        <Outputs>$(OutDir)Models\%(Filename).pum</Outputs>
        <Command>"$(SolutionDir)..\..\bin_$(PlatformTarget)_$(Configuration)_ContentCompiler\ContentCompiler" -o "$(OutDir)Models\%(Filename).pum" "%(FullPath)"</Command>
      </CompileModels>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(CompileModels)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="True"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(IntDir)$(ProjectName).tlog\"
      ErrorListRegex="(?'CATEGORY'ERROR|WARNING): (?'FILENAME'.+):(?'LINE'\d+): (?'TEXT'.*)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I would expect the CustomBuild to work the same way as the first one and make new tlog files to check. Currently it just executes the MakeDir task and then says: "All outputs are up-to-date".

*Edit:*
After some more testing I found out that the second CustomBuild task doesn't even want to run if I disable the first one. The target still gets called in both scenarios ("CompilePlutoniumModels called!" is being logged). But even a simple echo doesn't want to log on its own:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)pum.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="PuModel">
      <Targets>CompilePlutoniumModels</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompilePlutoniumModels" Condition="'@(PuModel)' != ''" BeforeTargets="FinalizeBuildStatus">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Models;$(IntDir)$(ProjectName)_$(MSBuildThisFileName).tlog"/>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="CompilePlutoniumModels called!"/>

    <ItemGroup>
      <CompileModels>
        <Command>echo CompileModels called!</Command>
      </CompileModels>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(CompileModels)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="True"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(IntDir)$(ProjectName)_$(MSBuildThisFileName).tlog\"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that the Sources property in the CustomBuild task would be a link to the item that would contain the build step. I figured out that this needs to have the same name as the ItemType or ContentType. So I changed my second targets file to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)pum.xml" />
    <AvailableItemName Include="PuModel">
      <Targets>CompilePlutoniumModels</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CompilePlutoniumModels" Condition="'@(PuModel)' != ''" BeforeTargets="FinalizeBuildStatus">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(OutDir)Models;$(IntDir)$(ProjectName)_$(MSBuildThisFileName).tlog"/>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PuModel>
        <Outputs>$(OutDir)Models\%(Filename).pum</Outputs>
        <Command>call "$(SolutionDir)..\..\bin_$(PlatformTarget)_$(Configuration)_ContentCompiler\ContentCompiler" -o "$(OutDir)Models\%(Filename).pum" "%(FullPath)"</Command>
      </PuModel>
    </ItemGroup>

    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(PuModel)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="True"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(IntDir)$(ProjectName)_$(MSBuildThisFileName).tlog\"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```